# How to return a custom error message from graphene?

Tags: django, graphene-django

I created the following class to update the post in specific conditions but if the conditions == false, then I need to return

> { "message": "Only the owner of the post and the admin (website's wonr) can edit and delete this post "}

But the JsonResponse doesn't work like this with RestFramework!

```
class UpdatePost(graphene.Mutation):
      # owner(added_by)+admin can update and delete
      class Arguments:
            id = graphene.Int(required=True)
            description = graphene.String()
      post = graphene.Field(schema.Posts)
      @classmethod
      def mutate(cls, root, info, id, description):
            post = models.Post.objects.get(id=id)
            if (info.context.user == post.added_by):
                  post.description = description
                  post.save()
                  return CreatePost(post=post)
            else:
                 JsoneResponse({"message": "Only the owner of the post and the admin(website's wonr) can edit and delet this post"})
```

Comment: Use a django form and generate the error from the form - https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/mutations/#django-forms

Comment: I don't know how to do that?